# Icinga2 nagvis problems

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

I am trying to get the NagVis module working with Icinga2, but after following the installation guides for both NagVis and the Icinga2 module, I am getting

```
The requested URL /nagvis-sys/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php was not found on this server.
```

When I go onto the module on the UI.
I also cannot navigate to the nagvis ui outside of icinga2.

I have looked at this topic here: Issues with Icingaweb and Nagvis integration after moving to root but I do not really understand the solution, and I have tried to follow it, and it still does not work.
I should mention that I am working inside the docker image of IcingaWeb2, not a normal installation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.